# Find common substring of > 1 character length between two strings in JS

Tags: javascript, substring

As per title, I need to find the common substring between two strings, which is longer than 1 character (so one that's one character long doesn't count).

I am trying to firstly compare two strings and if their characters match, to return true. Else, to return false. So far I have this code:

```
function SubstringTest(str1, str2){
 
   for ( let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < str2.length; j++) {
       
       if ((str1[i]) === (str2[j])) {
         
         return true
       } else {
         return false
       }
     }
   }
  }
SubstringTest("something", "home")
```

but I can't understand why it doesn't work. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Well for starters, `return` *immediately* exits the function, so your "loop" will only get into the first iteration before the whole thing is discarded. Second, your logic is basically saying "if every character of str1 is equal to every character of str2"... So your code will succeed only if both strings are like "aaaaaaaa" (without regard for length)

Comment: calling `return` exits the function, so it will only compare str1[0] and str2[0], then return the result.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why did you say "loop" in quotes though?

Answer (score 1):

This is the bruteforce, non-optimal solution:

```js
let commonSubstring = (str1, str2, minLen=1) => {
  
  let best = { len: 0, off1: null, off2: null };
  
  for (let off1 = 0; off1 < str1.length - minLen; off1++) {
    for (let off2 = 0; off2 < str2.length - minLen; off2++) {
      
      // Holds the number of characters that match
      let maxLen = Math.min(str1.length - off1, str2.length - off2);
      let len = 0;
      while (len < maxLen && str1[off1 + len] === str2[off2 + len]) len++;
      
      // Store this result if it's the best yet
      if (len > best.len) best = { len, off1, off2 };
      
    }
  }
  
  // We can now assert that str1.slice(best.off1, best.len) === str2.slice(best.off2, best.len)
  return best.len >= minLen ? str1.slice(best.off1, best.off1 + best.len) : null;
  
};

let tests = [
  [ 'mustard', 'hustler' ],
  [ 'lemon', 'harlem' ],
  [ 'marshmallow', 'hollow' ],
  [ 'marshmallow', 'marshal' ],
  [ 'jefferson', 'jeffery' ]
];

console.log('Examples:');
for (let [ str1, str2 ] of tests) {
  console.log(`Strings "${str1}" and "${str2}" share substring "${commonSubstring(str1, str2, 2)}"`);
}
```

The idea is to iterate all pairings of offsets within `str1` and `str2`. Eventually we'll arrive at the offsets where the longest sequence of shared characters occurs.

Note that I provided `minLen` as a parameter. You can set it to `2` if you want to discard any results less than `2` characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function SubstringTest(str1, str2){
       var matchingText = "";
       for ( let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
            if(str1[i] == str2[i]){
                matchingText+= str1[i];
            }
       }

       if(matchingText.length > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: This will only detect substrings that occur as the prefix of `str1` and `str2`